# QProgressBar text-align left wrong highlighting

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, stylesheet

I have a `QProgressBar` which I want to show the text left aligned inside the bar

```
progress = QProgressBar()
progress.setStyleSheet('text-align: left;')
```

But the highlighted text which normally follows the progress front is on the wrong position

[image: QProgressBar]

How can I make the highlighting follow the progress front?

Tested on Ubuntu, Kubuntu and Xubuntu.

(BTW `progress.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)` doesn't work here, don't know why)

Comment: It seems that Qt highlight 30% of your text, isn't it?

Comment: You're right. I double checked with different values. But normal behaviour (with align center) is to exactly follow the progress front.